# Postgresql - create user statement from a table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a table of user transactions (purchase, sale, etc). From this table I want to create a user statement to render in frontend

#### tb_transaction

---

```
id  | issuer_id | recipient_id | amount | operation_id
----|-----------|--------------|--------|---------|
 1  | 100       |  105         | 5      | 1
 2  | 101       |  105         | 3      | 1
 3  | 102       |  105         | 1      | 1
 4  | 103       |  105         | 5      | 2
 5  | 105       |  104         | 7      | 3
 6  | 102       |  104         | 1      | 4
```

#### tb_operation

---

```
id  | type      |
----|-----------|
 1  | PURCHASE  |
 2  | PURCHASE  |
 3  | PURCHASE  |
 4  | PURCHASE  |
```

Let's consider generating the user statement ID 105. I want to return the quantity grouped according to the operation.

```
[
  {user_id: 105, amount: 9, operation_id: 1, op: 'CREDIT'}, 
  {user_id: 105, amount: 7, operation_id: 3, op: 'DEBIT'}
]
```

I have some alternatives:

**1 . Create a new consolidated table for the user's statement. Example:**

```
id  | user_id   | amount | operation_id | operation
----|-----------|--------|--------------|----------|
1   | 105       |  9     | 1            | CREDIT  
2   | 100       |  5     | 1            | DEBIT  
3   | 101       |  3     | 1            | DEBIT  
4   | 102       |  1     | 1            | DEBIT 
5   | 105       |  5     | 2            | CREDIT 
6   | 103       |  5     | 2            | DEBIT 
7   | 104       |  7     | 3            | CREDIT 
8   | 105       |  7     | 3            | DEBIT 
9   | 104       |  1     | 4            | CREDIT
10  | 102       |  1     | 4            | DEBIT
```

**2 . Create a view materialized;**

**3 . Create query with cte and window function ( I'm afraid of performance, because the table has more than 10 million records );**

```
WITH w1_data AS (
 SELECT t.*,
 SUM(t.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.operation_id
 ORDER BY t.id ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS sum_group,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.operation_id
 ORDER BY t.id ASC) AS rnk
 FROM tb_transaction t
 WHERE issuer_id = 505 OR recipient_id = 505)
SELECT distinct on (w1.operation_id) operation_id, w1.*
 FROM w1_data w1
 ORDER BY w1.operation_id, w1.rnk DESC
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _afraid of performance_? Have you tried a regular query? With proper index, 10 million rows shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: Do you actually _have_  a performance problem? If yes, then please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @jarlh I have a query with cte and window function,however even with index it is slow. Question edited with example.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in fact the goal is to discuss a solution.